# palindromic substrings recursive solution using global variable

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Trying [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindromic-substrings/description/) with the recursive solution:

Recursively I am creating all the substrings and checking if it is palindrome or not.

Problem is that I want to get rid of global variable *count*.

```
class Solution(object):
    def countSubstrings(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        def palin(s):
            if s == s[::-1]:
                return True
            return False

        global count
        count = 0
        def helper(s, cur, dp):
            global count
            ret = 0
            if cur >= len(s)-1:
                return 0
            if cur in dp:
                return
            for i in range(cur+1, len(s)):
                if palin(s[cur:i+1]):
                    count += 1
                    ret = helper(s, i, dp)
                else:
                    ret = helper(s, i, dp)
            dp[cur] = ret
        helper(s, 0, {})

        return count + len(s)
```

What I have tried so far:

```
    def helper(s, cur, dp, count):
        ret = 0
        if cur >= len(s)-1:
            return count
        if cur in dp:
            return dp[cur]
        for i in range(cur+1, len(s)):
            if palin(s[cur:i+1]):
                ret = helper(s, i, dp, count + 1)
            else:
                ret = helper(s, i, dp, count)
        dp[cur] = ret
        return dp[cur]
```

Comment: FWIW, it would be helpful if you gave your variable full names or commented on what they mean. For example, `dp` is something like "dictionary of palidromes" right? Consider just calling it `palidromes` or `palidromes_dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your `count` variable in your recursive `helper` function (and increment as necessary).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? Does it return a wrong answer?

Comment: Can you show me what you tried (code, result, error)?

Comment: @combinatorist doesn't work means the result is wrong.

Comment: If you really want this to be recursive, you need `helper` return something (i.e. a substring) that can be put straight back into `helper`).

Comment: it can't be (the way it's implemented now) because the recursive call is done multiple times in a for-loop. If you have more suggestions please back them up with working code!

Comment: Actually, I'm concerned that this is for a technical interview website. Looks like the problems are supposed to take 45 minutes. I'll come back later if there's still genuine interest in the programming problem.

Comment: My only other hint (for now) is that recursive style shouldn't require the for loop.

Comment: @combinatorist: added what i tried so far. Anyway looks like with the current code what i have wouldn't enable it to pass a local variable to successive calls. Anyway I have a better DP solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new Counter class to keep track of your count

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def __add__(self,num):
        self.count+=num
        return self
```

Then modify your code to use that counter

```
class Solution(object):
def countSubstrings(self, s):
    """
    :type s: str
    :rtype: int
    """
    def palin(s):
        if s == s[::-1]:
            return True
        return False


    def helper(s, cur, dp,count): #make a parameter for Counter
        ret = 0
        if cur >= len(s)-1:
            return 0
        if cur in dp:
            return
        for i in range(cur+1, len(s)):
            if palin(s[cur:i+1]):
                count+=1
                ret = helper(s, i, dp,count) #pass in the Counter
            else:
                ret = helper(s, i, dp,count) #pass in here as well
        dp[cur] = ret

    a = Counter() #Change here
    helper(s, 0, {},a) #Change here

    return a.count + len(s) #Change here
```

The way you designed your counting and recursion, you have no choice but to use a mutable object to keep track of the count. And of course there are better ways to do recursion for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with as much recursion as I could think of (including your `palin`drome function):

```
class Solution(object):
    def countSubstrings(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        def palin(s):
            """recursively checks if bookends match on narrower substrings"""
            if len(s) <= 1:
                return True
            else:
                # checks if bookends match and inner substring is a palindrome
                return (s[0] == s[-1]) & palin(s[1:-1])

        def first_char_palin_count(s):
            """counts palindromes of all substrings with first char (pos 0)
                e.g. will check: "abba", "abb", "ab", "a", "" in palin()
            """
            if len(s) <= 0:
                return 0
                # if s is palindrome + shorter palindromes with first char
            else:
                return palin(s) + first_char_palin_count(s[:-1])

        def helper(s):
            """counts palindromes in all substrings"""
            if len(s) <= 0:
                return 0
            else:
                # first char palindromes + palindromes not including first char
                return first_char_palin_count(s) + helper(s[1:])

        return helper(s)
```

Notice:

- I need 2 functions in my recursion:

  - one to handle all substrings that include the first character (calls itself)
  - another (called `helper` to match yours) to handle all substrings (with and without first character)
- I don't need to pass anything but substrings around (no count variable global or local!), because the recursion implicitly the results of all its subproblems (substrings in this case).

Comment: In case you're new to SO, don't forget to up-vote answers, comments etc that helped. :)